# Where is this flag from?

Tags: europe, identify-this

I can't find what flag is between the Netherlands and Germany on this worldmap:
http://media.militaryphotos.net/photos/albums/album195/adl.jpg

[image: excerpt of map]

It is yellow with a (light) blue cross. There seems to be some red spots on it but those might be part of the face instead of the flag.

I have searched 3 flag searching websites, and checked all province flags from the Netherlands and Germany without success. The closest I got was the dutch [province Limburg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Dutch_Limburg) but that is no cross.

Does anyone know what it might be?

I'm sorry if this question is not suited for this stackexchange. I'm hoping that the collective knowledge might be able to help me because i'm stuck and very curious to what it is.

Comment: BTW, that map is super-offensive. It seems to have been designed to insult everyone. I think it's also supposed to be funny.

Comment: I'm glad you got your answer but I am going to close this now as having virtually nothing to do with Travel.

Comment: Maybe the proposed interfrisian flag? Though the color is not quite correct and it is geographically too far in the south. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groep_fan_Auwerk

Comment: Robert, yes I understand, I was afraid it was too far from the subject.
@starblue that really matches the red spots, but then the white cross is missing. Maybe there are different versions of the flag or the artist got it wrong. The locations on the map aren't precise anyway so it could be the answer as well.

Comment: Frisian is also likely because they are one of the better known regional people, like Bavarians who are also on the map.

Comment: @KateGregory: For the record, as a German (one of the countries that is featured most prominently in the excerpt shown in this question), I do not feel offended in the least, and I doubt the map (or the [polandball/countryball meme as a whole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polandball)) should reasonably insult anyone except for people who seriously promote and believe in country stereotypes.

Comment: There's also a Frisian flag that's very similar and listed at the bottom of this page: http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/flags/de-sh-nf.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Category:Blue and yellow flags](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category%3aBlue_and_yellow_flags) and [Category: Nordic Cross Flags](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category%3aNordic_Cross_flags) on Wikipedia I found only three flags that were a blue cross on yellow.

- [Flag of Kirovskoe](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aFlag_of_Kirovskoe.svg)
- [Flag of Finnish minority of Ingria](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aInkerinsuomalaisten_lippu.JPG)
- [Flag of Östergotland](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aFlag_of_Ostergotland.svg)

Neither of those locations are between Germany and the Netherlands though.

There is also a flag of blue on yellow that is a variant of the Netherlands flag:

[variant flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aRoyal_Standard_of_the_Netherlands.PNG)

It has some red stuff too that could be the red flecks in your picture.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort! I guess that last one, the dutch royal flag, is the most likely one. Why exactly it is put there I don't know. Maybe because the Dutch royal family has roots in Germany?

Anyway thanks, now I can sleep peacefully :)