# What is this flag?

Tags: canada, identify-this, ships

I am not sure if this is the correct place to post this type of question but I believe "travel" seems the most suitable.

Could anyone please identify what flag this is? I looked up all the flags with the Union Jack but I couldn't find a flag matching this one.

[image]

This is the picture of the ship that I saw the flag on. Picture was taken in Halifax, Nova Scotia, Canada.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel.

Comment: @JonathanReez - if this is not the right spot, can you please advise where I should post this question? Thank you.

Comment: I'm biased since I've answered but I've always thought [identify this](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this) is on-topic here. We have identified [plenty of buildings](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture+identify-this) which are no more or less about travel. Interestingly you @JonathanReez have answered a [recent one](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/73292/32134).

Comment: @mts you can travel to a building/location. You can't travel to a flag.

Comment: One could argue (but that is up to the OP) that upon seeing an exotic flag/ship they feel the wish to travel there, just as with buildings. Also we encounter flags more when traveling. I realize these are subtleties and I'll leave the rest to the community. @JonathanReez.

Comment: @JonathanReez While I'm not sure whether I agree with you or with mts, I guess the advantage of agreeing with you would be that I would be able to *flag* this question as off-topic.

Comment: I've created a [meta question](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/3811/41775) regarding whether this is on or off-topic.

Comment: @BustedSanta http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93500/geography

Comment: Might be helpful if you give more details of what sort of ship it was on (ie historic or still in use), and whereabouts you saw it. Plus a photo of the whole ship if possible.

Comment: @vclaw - picture and info added...

Comment: @mts: [tag:identify-this] is a tag on the site. That does not mean "identify this is on topic". Basically questions about identifying this which constitute a problem encountered related to travel are on topic. But "identify this brand of truck tyre" would not be on topic. So yes we identify things, but that still leaves open to discussion the question of what things we identify, and under which circumstances. A flag of a company, promotion, brand, sports team would probably be off-topic. Geopolitical flags of various kinds might require more thought.

Comment: Possible precedent: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1332

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is the [blue ensign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Ensign#Defaced_blue_ensign) worn by the Canadian Navy from 1957 to 1965.

[image]
Image source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Canadian_Blue_Ensign_1957-1965.svg

Comment: Dr. Cooper presents: [Fun With Flags](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gSwUg.png)...

Comment: Should the verb be *worn?* I would have said *flown.*

Comment: @phoog Ships wear ensigns/flags. Flags are flown on land.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I was afraid of that.